# Save and Run Rails Script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to write a set of commands - similar to what you'd find in a controller - but save it as a standalone file in my rails app that I could call up and run from the console?

For instance, something to loop through my database and run some ActiveRecord commands to modify data that may need to be cleaned up from time to time, but I don't want to live inside a controller. It's large - too large for me to copy/paste it into the rails console - which is why I'm trying to make a file out of it.

Comment: yes you can either write ruby and just execute it at the command line with ruby myubyfile.rb, or better still use rake, quick google rake tutorial will get you started on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your code into a separate file, let's say `myCode.rb` and run it from the console with `rails runner myCode.rb` (run this command from the directory you saved the file to). `rails runner` gives you access to your rails environment.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I took your advice, Tony, and looked into making my own rake tasks and that seemed to do the trick!
I made a new .rake file inside my lib/tasks folder and just copied and pasted my block of code inside there. I had to set it to inherit from the environment, as stated in the post I read, but it seems to work fine now - thanks for the tip!

Comment: Also, important to note that if it's not something that quite belongs in a rake task, you can use `rails runner`. Particularly useful for one-off tasks: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner